# How to override the default value in dropdown list

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, modelform, django-widget

In my web application, i have a drop-down list created using ModelForm which is rendering well, however, i can't set default text like "Choose One Option" or "Select One", rather its showing the default "----" which I would love to override

I have tried using forms.ChoiceField in my widgets but its still not making any difference

```
from django import forms
from . import models
from .models import FacultyData
```

class DepartmentCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = models.DepartmentData
    fields = ['fid', 'dept_name']

    data = []
    #data.append((None, 'select one'))
    data.append(('20', "---Choose One---"))
    CHOICES = FacultyData.objects.all()

    for v in CHOICES:
        # fname = "%s -- $%d each" % (v.faculty_name, v.created_on)
        data.append((v.id, v.faculty_name))
widgets = {
        'fid': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'dept_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Department Name'})
   }
```

I expect the default output to be "Select One" but the actual output is "-----"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
    class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
          your_field_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=FacultyData.objects.all(),empty_label="Select One")

         class Meta:
           model = DepartmentData
           fields = ("__all__")
           widgets = {  something   }
```

If it dont work show your model

Comment: the result is still the same.. it does not affect the form at all

Comment: Updated label to empty_label

Comment: Nothing has changed so far. If you can explain this more maybe it would be better

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your model:

```
         options = (
           ('','Select One'),
           ('One','One'),
           ('Two','Two')
          )
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, hope it helps:

```
class yourform(forms.ModelForm):     
##something##
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        self.fields["fieldname"].empty_label="fieldDefaulText"
```